# Send Facebook Notifications

Tags: facebook

I am working on "courses 2.0" application development team.This is one of the best application in facebook.

I want to send facebook notification to all our application user at once. I have all user id's as a string    format separated by commas.  I am able to send the notifications to these users  but some times some notifications are not sent.

Is there any limit for the notifications per day? If so , can we over come this limit?  please help me in this task

Thanks
Gopal

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are limit per day and you can do nothing about it as far as i know. It is the policy of facebook to limit those to a certain number on daily basis.

See your allocations:

Go to link developers->your application->statistics->allocation

Comment: I know there are 2 types of notifications i.e "user_to_user" and "app_to_user" is the limit is for both types?

Comment: app_to_user is 1 per user per day. user_to_user varies depending on how users respond within your app - if they click on them then your allocation goes up. Bear in mind that both types are being removed in around a month's time: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Developer_Roadmap